# Problema en Procedimiento PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql

!Buenas!

Vuelvo con otro ejercicio estancado... El cual es este:

> Crear un procedimiento para comprar un coche. El procedimiento deberá por tanto recibir los parámetros necesarios, y comprobar si existen y no están ya vendidos.

Y este es el código que he realizado y estoy probando:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE comprarCoche(vnombre VARCHAR, vmodelo VARCHAR)
IS
cursor existe IS select nombre, modelo from coche where nombre = vnombre 
and modelo = vmodelo;
cursor vendido IS select codcoche from venta, coche where coche.nombre = 
vnombre and coche.modelo = vmodelo;
vnombre2 coche.nombre%TYPE;
vmodelo2 coche.modelo%TYPE;
vcodcoche venta.codcoche%TYPE;
BEGIN
open existe;
open vendido;
fetch existe into vnombre2, vmodelo2;
fetch vendido into vcodcoche;
while existe%FOUND LOOP
if vnombre2 = vnombre and vmodelo2 = modelo THEN
    while vendido%FOUND LOOP
    if vcodcoche = venta.codcoche THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE("Coche disponible");
    END LOOP;
    END IF;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Creo que he complicado mas de la cuenta el ejercicio, hasta el punto que me he liado yo mismo. Mi idea era crear **dos** cursores, uno para después comprobar los coches vendidos y el otro para saber si existe o no en la tabla de coches. Y dependiendo del resultado indicar si es posible o no comprar el coche.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, por que no se como seguir...

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dándole unas vueltas he logrado obtener resultados, dejo el codigo con la solucion al problema para alguien interesado o con dudas similares a esta:

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE comprarCoche(vnombre VARCHAR, vmodelo VARCHAR)
IS
vnombre2 coche.nombre%TYPE;
vmodelo2 coche.modelo%TYPE;
vcodcoche coche.codcoche%TYPE;
cursor existe IS select codcoche from coche where nombre = vnombre2 and 
modelo = vmodelo2;
cursor vendido IS select codcoche from venta where codcoche = vcodcoche;
BEGIN
vnombre2 := vnombre;
vmodelo2 := vmodelo;
open existe;
fetch existe into vcodcoche;
if existe%NOTFOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Este coche no existe');
END IF;
while existe%FOUND LOOP
open vendido;
fetch vendido into vcodcoche;
    if vendido%FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Coche no disponible');
    else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Coche disponible');
    END IF;
    close vendido;
    fetch existe into vcodcoche;
END LOOP;
END;
```